# Are there any other factors to Mediterranean Defense Mission which could cause 100% success to fail?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

While reading the perks for completing the Assassin Guild Challenges one of them was that Recruits would be more efficient in Mediterranean Defense Missions.

Since I always make sure that I don't send Assassins out unless the success rate is 100% (which is what I did in Brotherhood, at most I needed 4 Assassin Rank recruits for a mission to be 100%).

I am wondering, even if a mission's success rate is at 100% when selecting recruits to dispatch, are there still factors which could lead to the mission failing, or is the Assassins Guild perk for Mediterranean Defense Missions just for those who want to risk missions which aren't on 100%

Comment: I believe it's a boost to your success rates. You need less assassins of less skill to complete missions. How the boost works, or whether there even is a boost rather than a bugged-out hole where a boost should be, is unknown to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is correct. Each individual assassin has a certain "skill level" depending on its rank; this skill level contributes to the success rate against missions of certain difficulties. The higher the rank, the higher the contribution of that particular assassin recruit versus the required skill level for 100% success rate.

The perks increase that skill contribution to the success rate. This allows you to send a lower level recruit than you would normally be able to and still achieve 100% success rate (even if the skill level of that recruit would, without that "perk", not give you the full 100%, if the threshhold of the mission difficulty is exceeded).

Just keep in mind, that even if an assassin recruit is max level and has everything, there are still certain missions that he / she can not complete alone. This is especially true for the 5- and 6-point difficulty missions, or even the 4-star difficulty missions.